# data fitting with fitting parameter depends on x axis data

Tags: fitting

I am stucking in fitting a dataset.
I have an experimental dataset which I want to model to extract some parameters, But unable to do it.
Here is my dataset:

```
\[Alpha]w = {{408.89473`, 1388.4913105131122`}, {406.96599`, 
   1383.2251117910585`}, {405.03723999999994`, 
   1377.6688258512638`}, {403.10848999999996`, 
   1371.3761646664366`}, {401.1797399999999`, 
   1365.0835034816091`}, {399.25099`, 
   1359.2148159227102`}, {397.32224`, 
   1353.502329173363`}, {395.39349`, 
   1347.5890128117346`}, {393.46474`, 
   1341.497181239189`}, {391.53599999999994`, 
   1335.2045200543616`}, {389.60725`, 1328.443256440877`}, {387.6785`,
    1321.8605080383093`}, {385.74975`, 1315.567846853482`}, {383.821`,
    1309.1636136618313`}, {381.89225`, 
   1302.6254940619933`}, {379.96349999999995`, 
   1296.6006056935414`}, {378.0347499999999`, 
   1290.7765469373717`}, {376.10601`, 
   1284.3053705416266`}, {374.17726`, 
   1277.5664213295072`}, {372.24851`, 
   1271.2514457433147`}, {370.31976`, 
   1264.4232389257363`}, {368.39100999999994`, 
   1256.568569645384`}, {366.46226`, 
   1248.7808435691263`}, {364.53351`, 
   1241.7518071392656`}, {362.60476`, 
   1234.5442554984886`}, {360.67602`, 
   1226.5333854085843`}, {358.74726999999996`, 
   1218.2547425023042`}, {356.8185199999999`, 
   1210.4447020246814`}, {354.88977`, 
   1202.8131767579757`}, {352.96102`, 
   1195.0477650830826`}, {351.03227`, 
   1187.4385542177417`}, {349.10351999999995`, 
   1180.431832189246`}, {347.17476999999997`, 
   1173.2242805484686`}, {345.24603`, 
   1165.1018384517413`}, {343.31728`, 
   1156.7785667427315`}, {341.38853`, 
   1149.102412673297`}, {339.45978`, 
   1141.1138569847574`}, {337.53103`, 
   1131.5856076020577`}, {335.60227999999995`, 
   1121.7226421988892`}, {333.67353`, 
   1112.997711265316`}, {331.74478`, 
   1104.6967539576715`}, {329.81604`, 
   1096.2619102418391`}, {327.88729`, 
   1087.8940097301006`}, {325.95853999999997`, 
   1079.4368516129032`}, {324.02978999999993`, 
   1070.9796934957062`}, {322.10104`, 
   1062.946509004437`}, {320.17229`, 
   1055.6273853568368`}, {318.24354`, 
   1047.8619736819437`}, {316.31479`, 
   1038.9138987347244`}, {314.38604999999995`, 
   1029.5418501615773`}, {312.4572999999999`, 
   1021.1739496498386`}, {310.52855`, 
   1013.6539963899563`}, {308.5998`, 
   1006.1563575314386`}, {306.67105`, 998.0562298360758`}, {304.7423`,
    989.7775869297958`}, {302.81354999999996`, 
   981.387372016693`}, {300.8847999999999`, 
   972.6847554844849`}, {298.95606`, 963.959824550912`}, {297.02731`, 
   956.0605264678306`}, {295.09856`, 949.3438916570751`}, {293.16981`,
    942.5156848394967`}, {291.24105999999995`, 
   934.8172163686972`}, {289.31231`, 927.1410622992624`}, {287.38356`,
    920.1120258694019`}, {285.45481`, 
   913.3953910586467`}, {283.52607`, 
   906.7680138533495`}, {281.59731999999997`, 
   900.5422958726164`}, {279.66856999999993`, 
   894.8967523273636`}, {277.73982`, 889.3404663875691`}, {275.81107`,
    883.8064948491394`}, {273.88232`, 
   878.6295537325437`}, {271.95357`, 873.8765862418761`}, {270.02482`,
    869.1905619553028`}, {268.0960799999999`, 
   864.5491664714582`}, {266.16733`, 859.729255776697`}, {264.23858`, 
   854.7308298710186`}, {262.30983`, 850.044805584445`}, {260.38108`, 
   846.2290429510921`}, {258.45232999999996`, 
   842.5248523245626`}, {256.5235799999999`, 
   838.4190024734695`}, {254.59483`, 834.6032398401172`}, {252.66609`,
    831.1891364313275`}, {250.73733999999996`, 
   827.9535482334553`}, {248.80859`, 
   825.0303616546879`}, {246.87983999999997`, 
   821.9956030690977`}, {244.95108999999997`, 
   818.6038140616728`}, {243.02234`, 815.8814570951873`}, {241.09359`,
    813.9624185778288`}, {239.16483999999997`, 
   812.0880088631992`}, {237.2361`, 
   810.1466559444757`}, {235.30734999999999`, 
   808.2722462298464`}, {233.3786`, 806.5986661274987`}, {231.44985`, 
   804.9474004265156`}, {229.5211`, 803.6754795487311`}, {227.59235`, 
   802.6713314873228`}, {225.6636`, 
   801.4663538136324`}, {223.73484999999997`, 
   800.1051753303898`}, {221.80611`, 798.5208528335004`}, {219.87736`,
    797.0481023434345`}, {217.94860999999997`, 
   796.5348711120479`}, {216.01986`, 797.1150455475283`}, {214.09111`,
    797.204303152987`}, {212.16235999999998`, 
   796.9365303366112`}, {210.23361`, 797.1596743502575`}, {208.30486`,
    797.94067839802`}, {206.37611999999996`, 
   798.5654816362297`}, {204.44737`, 
   798.364652023948`}, {202.51861999999997`, 
   798.6101104389588`}, {200.58986999999996`, 
   798.6547392416885`}, {198.66112`, 797.6729055816445`}, {196.73237`,
    796.0662686833904`}, {194.80361999999997`, 
   795.6646094588269`}, {192.87487`, 
   797.1819887516223`}, {190.94612999999998`, 
   799.3018568812629`}, {189.01738`, 800.7299785685992`}, {187.08863`,
    801.4440394122677`}, {185.15988`, 
   803.1176195146154`}, {183.23113`, 804.8804572224217`}, {181.30238`,
    805.058972433339`}, {179.37362999999996`, 
   804.1663963787533`}, {177.44488`, 802.7605890927812`}, {175.51614`,
    800.640720963141`}, {173.58738999999997`, 
   798.4985384321358`}, {171.65864`, 799.6365729017323`}, {169.72989`,
    800.6407209631408`}, {167.80113999999998`, 
   798.8109400512408`}, {165.87239`, 796.3563559011307`}, {163.94364`,
    794.7720334042416`}, {162.01488999999998`, 
   794.3480597783134`}, {160.08615`, 793.9687149551147`}, {158.1574`, 
   793.9910293564793`}, {156.22864999999996`, 
   792.3620780568609`}, {154.2999`, 790.9785851722534`}, {152.37115`, 
   790.9116419681598`}, {150.44239999999996`, 
   789.4388914780936`}, {148.51365`, 785.1098976133543`}, {146.5849`, 
   777.8130883671181`}, {144.65616`, 773.1493784819094`}, {142.72741`,
    771.2749687672798`}, {140.79865999999998`, 
   771.2303399645507`}, {138.86991`, 770.4493359167883`}, {136.94116`,
    767.7939221543968`}, {135.01241`, 
   763.5095570923863`}, {133.08366`, 755.9449750297749`}, {131.15491`,
    749.4291698313011`}, {129.22616999999997`, 
   742.1993037891591`}, {127.29742`, 
   737.8256811216903`}, {125.36866999999998`, 
   734.6793505292766`}, {123.43991999999999`, 
   727.985030119886`}, {121.51117`, 
   721.4469105200476`}, {119.58241999999998`, 
   715.6451661652421`}, {117.65366999999999`, 
   710.6913690622929`}, {115.72492`, 702.4573549587423`}, {113.79618`,
    698.172989896732`}, {111.86742999999998`, 
   695.3613753247881`}, {109.93868`, 691.4563550859766`}, {108.00993`,
    684.0702882342822`}, {106.08117999999999`, 
   668.3832640749431`}, {104.15243`, 655.7309985011944`}, {102.22368`,
    644.1051953902191`}, {100.29492999999998`, 
   638.6827958586124`}, {98.36618999999999`, 
   632.7917938983486`}, {96.43744`, 621.0321043791853`}}

\[Alpha]s = {{408.89473`, 1325.8763748050455`}, {406.96599`, 
   1320.4222059109632`}, {405.03723999999994`, 
   1315.1605370954949`}, {403.10848999999996`, 
   1309.642201508541`}, {401.1797399999999`, 
   1303.5677545833669`}, {399.25099`, 
   1297.3649742724492`}, {397.32224`, 
   1291.4830274258895`}, {395.39349`, 
   1285.9005251460633`}, {393.46474`, 
   1280.189689480495`}, {391.53599999999994`, 
   1274.478853814926`}, {389.60725`, 1268.5755180707424`}, {387.6785`,
    1262.3085710669534`}, {385.74975`, 
   1255.9988462679166`}, {383.821`, 1249.753288161752`}, {381.89225`, 
   1243.2296743864763`}, {379.96349999999995`, 
   1236.984116280311`}, {378.0347499999999`, 
   1231.1663361266228`}, {376.10601`, 
   1225.2843892800636`}, {374.17726`, 
   1219.1671645596412`}, {372.24851`, 
   1213.007162043972`}, {370.31976`, 
   1206.440770473449`}, {368.39100999999994`, 
   1199.5535454385677`}, {366.46226`, 
   1192.559375915568`}, {364.53351`, 
   1185.5224285973195`}, {362.60476`, 
   1178.357147893329`}, {360.67602`, 
   1170.9138115202281`}, {358.74726999999996`, 
   1163.04269719465`}, {356.8185199999999`, 
   1155.2785273571915`}, {354.88977`, 
   1147.9207465745856`}, {352.96102`, 
   1141.0549104373288`}, {351.03227`, 
   1134.1890743000718`}, {349.10351999999995`, 
   1127.152126981824`}, {347.17476999999997`, 
   1119.8585128920902`}, {345.24603`, 
   1111.9873985665122`}, {343.31728`, 
   1103.6671173908333`}, {341.38853`, 
   1095.667669679512`}, {339.45978`, 
   1087.4543329919522`}, {337.53103`, 
   1078.342662604191`}, {335.60227999999995`, 
   1069.6159923736586`}, {333.67353`, 
   1061.8732114338236`}, {331.74478`, 
   1054.4512639583465`}, {329.81604`, 
   1047.1790387662363`}, {327.88729`, 
   1039.949591369374`}, {325.95853999999997`, 
   1031.9501436580529`}, {324.02978999999993`, 
   1023.0523622465299`}, {322.10104`, 
   1013.8337473706492`}, {320.17229`, 
   1005.1284660377405`}, {318.24354`, 
   997.1504072240436`}, {316.31479`, 
   989.5359596699516`}, {314.38604999999995`, 
   981.8145676277406`}, {312.4572999999999`, 
   974.1145644831535`}, {310.52855`, 966.4359502361898`}, {308.5998`, 
   958.7787248868503`}, {306.67105`, 950.5867770969145`}, {304.7423`, 
   941.9456624568779`}, {302.81354999999996`, 
   933.7323257693183`}, {300.8847999999999`, 
   926.5028783724555`}, {298.95606`, 919.8937090066852`}, {297.02731`,
    913.0064839718041`}, {295.09856`, 
   905.8839810630612`}, {293.16981`, 
   898.8470337448133`}, {291.24105999999995`, 
   891.7245308360704`}, {289.31231`, 884.5164723368318`}, {287.38356`,
    877.7148028924464`}, {285.45481`, 
   871.1484113219234`}, {283.52607`, 
   864.9456310110057`}, {281.59731999999997`, 
   859.4272954240514`}, {279.66856999999993`, 
   854.0586821204645`}, {277.73982`, 848.326457557272`}, {275.81107`, 
   842.9578442536847`}, {273.88232`, 837.9528422097028`}, {271.95357`,
    833.3970070158223`}, {270.02482`, 
   829.3117275696662`}, {268.0960799999999`, 
   825.3761704068772`}, {266.16733`, 821.0128352916112`}, {264.23858`,
    816.7564446644644`}, {262.30983`, 
   812.7567208088038`}, {260.38108`, 
   808.5858857721522`}, {258.45232999999996`, 
   803.9658838854`}, {256.5235799999999`, 
   799.5169931796385`}, {254.59483`, 795.3675470406109`}, {252.66609`,
    791.6886566493082`}, {250.73733999999996`, 
   789.1006000368218`}, {248.80859`, 
   786.9403213768126`}, {246.87983999999997`, 
   784.3736536619505`}, {244.95108999999997`, 
   782.0208749233263`}, {243.02234`, 780.3097631134181`}, {241.09359`,
    778.4275401225192`}, {239.16483999999997`, 
   776.0533724862712`}, {237.2361`, 
   774.2139272906198`}, {235.30734999999999`, 
   772.887815637941`}, {233.3786`, 771.1339260327849`}, {231.44985`, 
   768.5886472155464`}, {229.5211`, 766.2144795792984`}, {227.59235`, 
   764.289478793152`}, {225.6636`, 
   763.0703116285924`}, {223.73484999999997`, 
   762.8992004476015`}, {221.80611`, 762.9847560380971`}, {219.87736`,
    762.8136448571058`}, {217.94860999999997`, 
   762.3644780070052`}, {216.01986`, 761.5089221020511`}, {214.09111`,
    759.8405880873904`}, {212.16235999999998`, 
   758.5358653323357`}, {210.23361`, 758.1508651751062`}, {208.30486`,
    758.3433652537209`}, {206.37611999999996`, 
   758.7283654109499`}, {204.44737`, 
   758.7711432061978`}, {202.51861999999997`, 
   759.3700323396656`}, {200.58986999999996`, 
   760.2469771422437`}, {198.66112`, 761.252255330565`}, {196.73237`, 
   762.3217002117573`}, {194.80361999999997`, 
   763.4553117858218`}, {192.87487`, 
   764.2680898955282`}, {190.94612999999998`, 
   764.3322565883996`}, {189.01738`, 764.6958678480052`}, {187.08863`,
    765.1236458004823`}, {185.15988`, 
   765.5728126505834`}, {183.23113`, 765.8508683196933`}, {181.30238`,
    765.9578128078126`}, {179.37362999999996`, 
   766.3642018626658`}, {177.44488`, 766.4283685555373`}, {175.51614`,
    765.7225349339503`}, {173.58738999999997`, 
   763.9472564311703`}, {171.65864`, 762.7280892666108`}, {169.72989`,
    761.6800332830416`}, {167.80113999999998`, 
   761.4447554091795`}, {165.87239`, 763.0061449357208`}, {163.94364`,
    765.6155904458309`}, {162.01488999999998`, 
   766.7705909175189`}, {160.08615`, 763.840311943051`}, {158.1574`, 
   761.0383663543263`}, {156.22864999999996`, 
   759.5411435206565`}, {154.2999`, 757.8514206083721`}, {152.37115`, 
   754.2794747051886`}, {150.44239999999996`, 
   750.3011397471518`}, {148.51365`, 748.7611391182345`}, {146.5849`, 
   746.0447491200052`}, {144.65616`, 741.0183581783998`}, {142.72741`,
    734.4947444031242`}, {140.79865999999998`, 
   732.3558546407387`}, {138.86991`, 732.7836325932161`}, {136.94116`,
    730.8158540118216`}, {135.01241`, 
   728.6341864541884`}, {133.08366`, 725.4044629129866`}, {131.15491`,
    721.5972391359408`}, {129.22616999999997`, 
   713.6191803222432`}, {127.29742`, 
   706.4111218230048`}, {125.36866999999998`, 
   701.3847308813993`}, {123.43991999999999`, 
   694.9038949013719`}, {121.51117`, 
   689.3641704167936`}, {119.58241999999998`, 
   685.4286132540046`}, {117.65366999999999`, 
   683.7175014440963`}, {115.72492`, 676.9372208973349`}, {113.79618`,
    671.2905519246376`}, {111.86742999999998`, 
   664.8952715351055`}, {109.93868`, 654.6072117780318`}, {108.00993`,
    644.7469299734356`}, {106.08117999999999`, 
   633.7958143900229`}, {104.15243`, 627.3363673076188`}, {102.22368`,
    621.9035873111602`}, {100.29492999999998`, 
   619.7219197535271`}, {98.36618999999999`, 
   612.877472513894`}, {96.43744`, 601.9477458281048`}}

ListLinePlot[{\[Alpha]w, \[Alpha]s}];
```

Here, the x axis (wavenumber) of both [Alpha]s and [Alpha]w are variable as one can see from the data.  [Alpha]s and [Alpha]w correspond to wavenumber dependent absorption coefficient of solute and water respectively.

Now, I have the following model by which I can get the [Alpha]s value in term of [Alpha]w and some other parameter.
[Alpha]s = [Alpha]w*(1 - [Phi]h - 0.0024) + [Alpha]h*[Phi]h

Here, [Alpha]s and [Alpha]w are experimentally obtained value, the paramaters to be adjusted here is [Phi]h and [Alpha]h. Again the boundary conditions for this are :
0<[Phi]h<1 and [Alpha]h>0 and [Alpha]h>0 should be parameter which vary with the change of x axis data i.e. teh value of [Alpha]h should be in such a way that the no of [Alpha]h array should be equal to the number of datpoints present in both [Alpha]s and [Alpha]w (no of datapoint present in both [Alpha]s and [Alpha]w=163), more specifically, the value of [Alpha]h should be wavenumber dependent i.e. for different value of x (wavenumber), we should get a different [Alpha]h like there will be different value of [Alpha]h at x=96.4374, x=98.3662, x=100.295.............x=408.895 (as one can see that there are data for [Alpha]s, [Alpha]w for those x values) i.e. [Alpha]s,[Alpha]w,[Alpha]h should have same datapoints. How can I get it?

Any help regarding this will be really helpful to me.

Comment: `\[Alpha]s` and `\ [Alpha]w` depend on the same independent variable? This variable should occur in your model too!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `\[Alpha]s[x] ,\[Alpha]w[x]` depend on the same variable `x`:

First interpolate the datasets

```
ip\[Alpha]w = Interpolation[ \[Alpha]w, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
ip\[Alpha]s = Interpolation[ \[Alpha]s, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

range of x

```
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[\[Alpha]s[[All, 1]]]
(* {96.4374, 408.895} *)
```

model

```
` ip\[Alpha]s[x] ~ ip\[Alpha]w[x]*(1 - \[CurlyPhi]h - 0.0024) + x*\[CurlyPhi]h`
```

minimization

```
J = # . # &[Table[-ip\[Alpha]s[x] +ip\[Alpha]w[x]*(1 - \[CurlyPhi]h - 0.0024) + \[Alpha]h*\[CurlyPhi]h, {x, Subdivide[xmin, xmax, 50]}]];
sol = NMinimize[J, {  \[CurlyPhi]h}]
(*{902.843, {\[CurlyPhi]h -> 0.0589715}}*)
```

show fit

```
Plot[Evaluate[{ip\[Alpha]s[x], ip\[Alpha]w[x]*(1 - \[CurlyPhi]h - 0.0024) + x*\[CurlyPhi]h} /. sol[[2]]], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Dashed, Red}}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is fine and your consideration is also in line to extract the parameters,  \[Alpha]h, \[CurlyPhi]h, but  teh value of \[Alpha]h should be x axis dependent i.e. for different value of x, we should get a different \[Alpha]h like there will be different value of \[Alpha]h at x=96.4374, x=98.3662, x=100.295.............x=408.895. How can I get it?

Comment: That's an important information, please modifiy your question!

Comment: I have updated the question as per your suggestion

Comment: Ok, see my modified answer! There is only one parameter `\[CurlyPhi]h` left to fit!

Comment: ok, I get get the \[CurlyPhi]h value from teh fit, but can you please let know how can I get the x dependent \[Alpha]h value?

Comment: One way to get the \[Alpha]h value may be by putting the \[CurlyPhi]h in the solution.

Comment: What you call `\[Alpha]h` (I called it `x`) is the independent variabel, not a model parameter!  I assumed your datasets depend on `\[Alpha]h`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131687/discussion-between-p-pyne-and-ulrich-neumann).